# Performance impact while converting a file (average 5-6 MB) to Base64encoded string using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file-upload, w3wp

Following is the exact scenario in the ASP.NET MVC application we are currently developing.

---

There is one particular webpage from where users are expected to    upload a file. (Max size limit 10 MBs).

There is one button on this page which should pick the file from the location, convert it to Base64encoded string, and send it to an external SOAP serivce.

I know how to achieve this, so my question is not related to code. But my main concern and the debates among our team members is related to performance.
That is, some of the team members are in opinion to create a separate job/ process and host it on a separate server, as they feel if there are 5-6 parallel requests to convert a file to Base 64 encoded string at the same time, then it will increase a lot of load on **w3wp** process and will impact performance of overall application to a great extent.

Currently we are not sure if that can really cause the issue. Because we already allow users to upload file at multiple places in the application, and we never faced this issue of additional load on w3wp. So I believe there shouldn't be an issue when we convert the file to Base64. But I need to provide some facts/ proof to support my claim!

Any inputs on this from the experts here would be of a great help.

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to simulate those 5-6 parallel requests to see what would happen to your process?

Comment: Not at the moment, because we have to just work on the approach and architecture. SOAP service is still not available to us. But its just an assumption that w3wp would be more impacted if we perform conversion from a file to base64 encoded string in the same process.